# SMFL "Cannot be Referenced, it is a deleted function"

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm having an issue with my DrawCircles(window); method.

When I try to pass in "window" I get the error in my title.

Any idea how I could resolve this? also, an explanation would be appreciated, thank-you.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<sf::CircleShape> Shapes;


int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Conduit");




    while (window.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        DrawCircles(window);            // ERROR IS THIS LINE.
        //window.draw(shape);  
        window.display();
    }

}


void RenderCircle()
{
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    shape.setRadius(40.f);
    shape.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);

    Shapes.push_back(shape);
}

void DrawCircles(sf::RenderWindow window)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Shapes.size(); i++)
    {
        window.draw(Shapes.at(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding a prototype of your DrawCircles method at the top of your code. And add all the other method's prototypes. Try this:

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;


    void DrawCircles(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    vector<sf::CircleShape> Shapes;
    .. rest of code

void DrawCircles(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Shapes.size(); i++)
    {
        window.draw(Shapes.at(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well, that's literally all of them, asides from void RenderCircle() itself.

Comment: Thank-you, this worked, any explanation why this works? is it something to do with pointers?

Comment: Glad it worked. It is all about copying a sf::RenderWindow. If you do not use a & (which means a reference) - you are trying to copy your sf::RenderWindow. However sf::RenderWindow cannot be copied (to copy objects, classes use Copy Constructors, which sf::RenderWindow doesn't have). If you use a reference here, you are not copying or trying to copy anything, you are just using the same exact sf::RenderWindow that you declared in your main function. Hope it helps.